# Unit Testing Buttons in C# - .NET Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have a Windows Form Application that is just a bunch of buttons. I want to be able to test them with something like button1.PerformClick(); in my unit test class.

Is there anyway to do this without creating a method for each button inside my main program like:
public void TestButton1Click(){ button1.PerformClick(); }

For some reason the button variables don't show up in the context of the unit test.
Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yeah your buttons would not ordinarily be available to your unit test because they are automatically private (changing them in your designer to be internal will work... until you compile).

A minimally-invasive and viable option is to use Fakes (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx) but I only know of them and haven't used them.

How I normally test my WinForms buttons is I use the Humble Object pattern (http://xunitpatterns.com/Humble%20Object.html) and basically all logic that would have been in my buttons are in a separate object I can easily test. Then all my buttons do is call that object. If my code gets complicated with all sorts of visual updates to do, then its rudimentary to turn to the MVP architecture at that point.

Answer (score 0):

**Extension Method to perform button click**

```
public static class TestHelper{
   public static Results ClickMe (this Button button){
     button.Click();
     var results = GetResults(button);
     return results;
   }
}
```

You must have addressiblity to the button at run time.
Use it like this.

```
var results =this.ButtonName.ClickMe();
if(results.Ok == true) { //everything worked }
```

The Results class is anything you want to create to show the response of the click.

**Unit Testing**

Typically in Unit Testing you don't have to go to the GUI layer instead you test the Button click event handler.